# Flip the elements of slist in Racket

Tags: racket

I want to define a function `flip` that flips 'i' to 'o', 'o' to 'i', 'z' to 'n' and 'n' to 'z'. for example: `(flip '(i i o n))` → `'(o o i z)`

I have the following codes:

```
(define (flip s)
 (cond
   [(eq? s 'n) '(z)]
   [(eq? s 'z) '(n)]
   [(eq? (first s) 'o) (list 'i (flip (rest s)))]
   [(eq? (first s) 'i) (list 'o (flip (rest s)))]
 ))
```

But when I run the following:

```
> (flip '(i i o n))
```

it results the following error message:

```
cond: all question results were false
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What `#lang` are you using?

Comment: No matter which one, though... Two of the cases are very different from the other two. Does that seem right?

Comment: Start your interpreter and compare `(cons 'i '(i o n))` to `(list 'i '(i o n))`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two cases in the form: `[(eq? s 'n) '(z)]` and two cases in the form: `[(eq? (first s) 'o) (list 'i (flip (rest s)))]`?

And that isn't the only error- you're using `list` instead of [`cons`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._cons%29%29) and you forgot on the base case- what if `s` is an empty list?

Correct solution would be:

```
(define (flip s)
  (cond
    [(null? s) '()]
    [(eq? (first s) 'n) (cons 'z (flip (rest s)))]
    [(eq? (first s) 'z) (cons 'n (flip (rest s)))]
    [(eq? (first s) 'o) (cons 'i (flip (rest s)))]
    [(eq? (first s) 'i) (cons 'o (flip (rest s)))]))
```

Test:

```
> (flip '(i i o n))
'(o o i z)
```

If your language supports that, you could also use [hash-tables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html):

```
(define (flip s)
  (map (lambda (c) (hash-ref (hash 'n 'z 'z 'n 'o 'i 'i 'o) c))
       s))

> (flip '(i i o n))
'(o o i z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first two clauses compare a list to a symbol, and those will never be equal.

Another solution is to see that this fits into the most common list recursion pattern; "make a list with the same structure but with the elements replaced by something else":

```
(define (recurse s)
    (if (empty? s)
        '()
        (cons <some transformation of (first s)> (recurse (rest s)))))
```

Specifically, if you had a function `flipped` that took a symbol and returned the "flipped" symbol, you could just write

```
(define (flip s)
  (if (empty? s)
      '()
      (cons (flipped (first s)) (flip (rest s)))))
```

and if you have encountered `map`, this is even simpler:

```
(define (flip s)
    (map flipped s))
```

Implementing `flipped` left as an exercise.